# writing a base task for celery that will know if workers are up

Tags: python, task, celery, worker

I'm trying to write a base task class that will check the availability of workers before it does something.
By reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506914/detect-whether-celery-is-available-running) post here, I've come up with the following:

```
class BaseTask(Task):
    def apply_async(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not celery.control.inspect().stats():
            raise Exception("workersDown")
        Task.apply_async(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

However, this seems to work only for the first time.
I know that a [task is not instantiated each time](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#instantiation), but it is related?
Is there any other way to achieve what I want?

**EDIT:**

I have found that setting the base task as abstract helps but still produces some false positives (sometimes the exception is raised although the workers are up):

```
class AnotherTask(Task):
    abstract = True

    def apply_async(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not celery.control.inspect().stats():
            raise Exception("workersDown")
        Task.apply_async(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Celery scheduled list returns None](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236131/celery-scheduled-list-returns-none)

Answer (score 0):

You can call `inspect()` only once for given celery app instance. Below you have small code snippet, which you can use in your task:

```
from celery import Celery

def inspect(method):
    app = Celery('app', broker='amqp://')
    return getattr(app.control.inspect(), method)()


class BaseTask(Task):
    def apply_async(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not inspect('stats'):
            raise Exception("workersDown")
        Task.apply_async(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Why can I inspect only once for a given celery app? Also, can you point me to the relevant documentation for that?

Comment: @Ofir, I have no idea why is that. I suppose it's a bug and my solution is just a workaround. I haven't seen any documentation about, I came up with this solution after digging into djcelery command code.